# Prove l1 and l-infinity norm equality.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

I struggle with a simple problem which is to show that L1 norm is equivalent to L-infinity norm ($\ \mathbb{R}^n$). I know that this holds
$$\ ||x||_1 \ge ||x||_\infty $$
so the C2 will be equal to 1.

I can't find the C1 so that $$\ ||x||_\infty  \ge C1||x||_1$$

Comment: On which space? $\Bbb R^n$? if so, $\|x\|_1\le n\|x\|_\infty.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes $\ R^n$. How would the proof of that look like?

Comment: 1/2: then edit your question to specify it. 2/2: follow the link to the duplicate or simply: sum up the $n$ inequalities $|x_k|\le\|x\|_\infty.$

Comment: No, the duplicate is simply the post I linked to (and its accepted answer). But the hint in my previous comment is sufficient.